# Loader image before webView finish loading Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have simple webview.
All I need is the image to disappear after webView finish loading.

This function work, but I get error on line "imageView.isHidden = false"

error is : " Use of unresolved identifier 'imageView' "

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      imageView.isHidden = false
   }
```

Full code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
    
    public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageName = "icon.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height:screenHeight)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
       
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
    
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      imageView.isHidden = false
   }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    
    var webView: WKWebView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    }
    
    public var screenHeight: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageName = "icon.png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height:screenHeight)
        view.addSubview(imageView)
       
        let myURL = URL(string:"https://google.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }
    
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      imageView.isHidden = false
   }
    
    
}
```

try this

Comment: this will not work - where did you create `UIImageView` or assign `imageView`? It will crash if you run the app...

Comment: @charlyatwork what you mean? If I publish this app, it will block from Apple? I'm asking, because it is publishing first app for me. I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and this source work.

Comment: It was edited by @Nithin.PMolethu yesterday (The first version of that would crash), however the new code from the answer assigns the `UIImageView` by `imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)` - which is ok-ish

Comment: @charlyatwork actually edited 4 minutes after. thanks !.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign it to an instance property (like you already did for `var webView: WKWebView!`) and assign it - then you have access to it at a later point in time.

`self.imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)`